# If I were to stand on a flat torus, would I be able to see myself from behind?

Tags: geometry, geodesic

The title pretty much says it all : from any point on a flat torus, there is at least one geodesic from that point that goes back to it. And, by definition of a flat torus, that geodesic is a line. So, if I look toward the direction pointed by that geodesic, do I see myself from behind ?

If the anwser is no, why ? I have very little knowledge about how a flat torus can not be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with full ($C^2$) regularity, so I suppose that we need to be at least in $\mathbb{R}^4$ for the question to make sense, but then maybe it is hard/not relevant to talk about light trajectory (obviously I am *not* considering any relativistic effect whatsoever).

Comment: This question cannot be answered until you specify the trajectory of light. Does light move along the geodesics of your torus? Then yes, you see yourself from behind. Is your torus really a donut embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ and light propagates along straight lines in $\mathbb R^3$? Then if you stand on the donut you see the horizon far away.

Comment: It's not just a torus, but a _flat_ torus. See answers from Karl and Lee Mosher to get the idea :)

Comment: I get the idea. Again, the answer is in my previous comment. You can realise the flat torus as a quotient, mathematically, but if you embed it in a higher dimensional space then light might choose to propagate according to the geodesics of that bigger space. In that case, you do not see yourself from behind.

Comment: Have you played the game Portal? I presume it would look something like [this](https://rhapsodistreviews.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/portal-screenshot.jpg) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: if you're "in" the torus and light rays travel along its geodesics, then we can think of the torus as a flat square with its top & bottom and left & right edges identified. In terms of what you can see, it's equivalent to being in an infinite plane with a copy of yourself at each integer point; you see many copies of yourself from behind.

Edit: I think the answer is no to the question you mean to ask. Note that (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Flat_torus)) the flat torus (e.g. as realized by the standard embedding in $\Bbb R^4$) is flat *in the sense that the surface of a cylinder is flat*, i.e. it has zero [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature). Of course you don't see yourself from behind when standing on a cylinder in $\Bbb R^3$, and more generally, if you're in a Euclidean space where light travels in straight lines, then it doesn't matter what you're standing on, you won't see yourself from behind.

Comment: Thanks ! See reply to Lee Mosher :)

Comment: @Clem see my edits.

Comment: Thanks again ! You're right and I'll accept your answer. One more thing : Gaussian curvature is the product of principal curvatures, so zero Gaussian curvature means that one of the principal curvature is zero. But the principal direction it defines can't be a line (a torus is bounded so it can not include an unbounded line), so I guess that means this geodesic isn't a principal direction for every point of the torus it goes through. Am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need $\mathbb R^4$ at all to address your questions. In fact the Euclidean plane itself will suffice to depict what you will see. Here's a picture showing a head looking up outward from the torus:

[image]

The point is that the flat torus may be abstractly described by starting with the unit cell, and then identifying each point on the left edge with the corresponding point on the right edge (and similarly for the top/bottom edges). So light beams heading horizontally outward at the left side of the unit cell will reappear heading horizontally inward at the right side.

Now imagine that head seen in profile, looking to the right. That head will clearly see the back of itself.

Comment: Thank you ! The thing that makes me doubt is about « standing on ». Your heads are as flat as the torus, but what if I am a 3D-human being standing **on** the surface of a flat torus ? Can I still consider the whole situation as equivalent as standing on an infinite plane of repeating cells, as you and Karl suggest ?

Comment: Your comment is departing from mathematical abstraction, making it difficult to address from a mathematical standpoint. My answer (and the answer of @Karl) are both set in the same abstract mathematical setting.